# How do I specify the login_hint in FeatherJS OAuth?

Tags: oauth, feathersjs, feathers-authentication

After setting up OAuth in FeathersJS to authenticate with Microsoft, it all works fine.  What I can't get working is passing the login_hint through to Microsoft.

When I put it in the config file (`"custom_params": {"login_hint":"test@example.com"}`) then it works, but it's static instead of dynamic.  I haven't managed to figure out how to make it dynamic.

In my front-end, I redirect to `http://localhost:3030/oauth/microsoft` which uses an custom/extended strategy.  Adding the `login_hint=me@example.com` to the URL doesn't appear to make a difference.

I also tried using it as a dynamic property as described on the FeathersJS site without any luck: https://feathersjs.com/api/authentication/oauth.html#dynamic-override

If someone knows how to get this working then I'd appreciate the help.